# Are URL based SSL / certificates possible at IIS?

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis, url

Is there a way to change the used certificate / ssl encryption depending on the visited url? 
We are using IIS 7 and later.

**Edit:**

We plan to develop and deploy web applications to our customers. It is wanted that the communication to "our" URLs on the webserver is using a seperate certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the certificate depend on the path inside the URL this is not possible: The full URL is only revealed inside the SSL tunnel, that is after the SSL handshake is already done and certificate was send and ciphers determined. Also, a certificate identifies a hostname, so having it depend on a path component does not make sense.

If you want the certificate depend on the hostname only this is possible if you have a different IP for each hostname. With SNI (supported by all modern browser, but not with IE8/XP) this would also be possible if hostnames share the same IP, but IIS 7 does not support SNI.

> It is wanted that the communication to "our" URLs on the webserver is using a seperate certificate.

In this case use a separate hostname and IP for "your" URLs. Then you can easily have a separate certificate too.

Comment: I was thinking about establishing an new SSL tunnel depending on the url. Isn't that possible? (Thanks for the hint with iis 7. I Was convinced that SNI is fully supported there) Sorry I can't vote your answer up with my reputation.

Comment: In theory you might do a renegotiation inside an existing SSL tunnel and change the certificate. In practice this will not work with most browsers because of counter measures against the [triple handshake attack](https://www.secure-resumption.com/#disclosure). What you could do is to redirect the user to another host with another certificate. But in this case the user will create a new connection and not use the existing. It might help to describe what the problem is that you are trying to solve instead of focusing on a specific technology.

Comment: question is edited

Comment: see edited answer.